# Handling axis scale change when a legend item is clicked & hidden

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm drawing markers to show the last value in a series to the extreme right of the chart using the last value.plotY as the y co-ordinate and the chart width as the x. This is working fine.

However clicking legend items to hide some series will occasionally rescale the axis to best fit the series still displayed, unfortunately as my markers are just dumb drawings they don't respond to this scale.

I could use ignoreHiddenSeries to stop this scaling behaviour but I would like to keep it and find a way to reposition my markers to the correct place. Is there a axis rescale event or a way of catching this rescaling so that I may be able to redraw or move my markers?

Hopefully there is an easy way to do this, I'm just not sure how best to recognise and work with this rescaling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are rendering some shape, returned is that object, for example:

```
 var myShape = chart.renderer.circle(..); // create element
 myShape.add(); // add circle to the SVG
 myShape.attr({
     r: 150 // set new radius for circle
 })
```

Now since you have access to that shape, you can update it's dimensions/position/anything in redraw event:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        redraw: function() { 
            // recalculate new position and then update shape:
            myShape.attr( ... ); 
        }
    }
}
```